# Unsupported class file major version 64

Tags: flutter, gradle, version, unsupported-class-version

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\D\FitCoachApp\fit_coach_app\android\build.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'D:\D\FitCoachApp\fit_coach_app\android\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 64

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6whao.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKYeM.png)

Comment: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

Comment: Please run `flutter doctor -v` in terminal and share result in your question.

Comment: I updated the kotlin version and it was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

In my case I could sorted it by changing the gradle JVM.
Settings... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
then downgrade the Gradle JVM. In my case I had to change from 20 to 17.
After go to build.gradle and click on syncup button

Comment: You're a lifesaver, downgrading from 20 to 17 fixed it for me too